# FPS limit in cocos2d python

Tags: python, cocos2d-x, frame-rate

I am new to use cocos 2d python and I face a problem now: I want to limit the FPS below 60, but it seems that the python cocos2d framework doesn't provide the interface to limit the FPS.

My code framework is as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cocos
import pyglet
from cocos.actions import *
from cocos.director import *
from cocos.scene import *
from game_controller import *
import common

def main():
    #initialize director
    director.init( width=common.visibleSize["width"], height=common.visibleSize["height"], caption="Flappy Bird")

    #turn off display FPS
    #director.show_FPS = True

    #run
    gameScene = Scene()
    game_start(gameScene)

    if director.scene:
        director.replace(gameScene)
    else:
        director.run(gameScene)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look around pyglet instead cocos2d for fps limitation. Answer example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735825/801924